# Add link at top bar in railsAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm using railsAdmin plugin in Rails4, now I want to add a new link on the top bar in railAdmin, on the right of Home link, can anybody tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Modify `/app/views/layouts/rails_admin/_secondary_navigation.html.haml`

After `%li= link_to t('admin.home.name'), main_app_root_path`

You would do something to the effect of:

```
%li= link_to 'My Link', my_link_path
```

Assuming that you're linking to a path within your project, you can use $rake routes to figure out the correct route name.

If you're linking externally you would replace my_link_path with http://theurl.com

Comment: This is not working